# SQL - how to insert to table if value does not exist in other table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
Customers( id, name, is_deleted)

Orders(id, name, amount, customer_id)
```

Now, I would like to do insert into `Order` table, but only if customer is not deleted.

I created a script:

```
Insert into Orders values (....)
```

But I don't know how to check if customer `is_deleted=false` before I insert.
I tried to do select first, but then I have no idea what to do if there is no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`INSERT SELECT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

```sql
insert into Orders 
select :p_id, :p_name, :p_amount, customer.id 
  from Customers customer 
 where customer.id=:p_customer_id 
   and customer.is_deleted = 'false'
```

It will insert row only if there is a customer with specified id and it's `is_deleted=false`.